# Gemfile.lock Use in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, gemfile

What is the purpose of "Gemfile.lock" in Rails?
I have been searching around for but could not find a satisfactory answer.

Comment: The best resource about this is definitely the article ["Clarifying the Roles of the .gemspec and Gemfile"](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/12/16/clarifying-the-roles-of-the-gemspec-and-gemfile/). Reading it will clarify all your doubts about this topic.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You should read all the documentation from the `bundler` gem: http://gembundler.com/

> THE GEMFILE.LOCK
>
> When you run bundle install, Bundler will persist the full names and
>   versions of all gems that you used (including dependencies of the gems
>   specified in the Gemfile(5)) into a file called Gemfile.lock.
>
> Bundler uses this file in all subsequent calls to bundle install,
>   which guarantees that you always use the same exact code, even as your
>   application moves across machines.
>
> Because of the way dependency resolution works, even a seemingly small
>   change (for instance, an update to a point-release of a dependency of
>   a gem in your Gemfile(5)) can result in radically different gems being
>   needed to satisfy all dependencies.
>
> As a result, you SHOULD check your Gemfile.lock into version control.
>   If you do not, every machine that checks out your repository
>   (including your production server) will resolve all dependencies
>   again, which will result in different versions of third-party code
>   being used if any of the gems in the Gemfile(5) or any of their
>   dependencies have been updated.

Answer (score 6):

`Gemfile.lock` ensures that other developers on your app, as well as your deployment environment, use exactly the same third-party code as you just installed.